# redux-form onSubmit function not firing

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I've been looking at many ways to do this and have even made a HOC and changed it to a class component. I've tried the few ways I have seen such as invoking handleSubmit with the prop. I am using redux tools and I am used to seeing something such as submit_failed or submit_success, but I don't see that  and I don't know why the onSubmit function doesn't fire. Here is a sample of one of the ways I did it where I follow the simple example in redux-form docs:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Form, Button, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {signup} from '../../actions/user-actions';
import { required, minValue7, email, renderField } from '../helpers/validations';


let SignupForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props.signup;
  return (
      <Grid centered columns={2}>
        <Grid.Column className="home">
          <Form className="forms" onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
            <Form.Field inline>
               <Field 
                name="username" 
                component={renderField}
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Username"
                label="Username"
                validate={[required]}
              />
            </Form.Field>

            <Form.Field inline>
               <Field 
                name="email" 
                component={renderField}
                type="email" 
                placeholder="Email"
                label="Email"
                validate={[required, email]}
              />
            </Form.Field>

             <Form.Field inline>
               <Field 
                name="password" 
                component={renderField} 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Password"
                label="Password"
                validate={[required, minValue7]}
              />
            </Form.Field>
            <Link to={'/signup2'}>
              <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
            </Link>
          </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>

  )
}

SignupForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'form1'
})(SignupForm)

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
 return {
  userSignup: state.userSignup
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return bindActionCreators({signup}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignupForm)
```

Also I have tried it where I do `const {handleSubmit} = props` and then change ```onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.signup)}

Comment: Why are you wrapping the submit button in a redux-router Link?

Comment: So it redirects to the next form once hit

Comment: So you want the `Link` to fire the same time your event handler fires. I'm not sure what will actually happen, but wouldn't be surprised if the redirect happens which then precludes the handler from happening. Spitballing here, but create a component for each wizard step - `WizardStep1`, `WizardStep2`, etc... Instead of using `Link`, your event handler(s) could accept data from the form and based on that determine which step should be the current step and save that to state. Then, in your page, your `render()`  method could check to see which step is current, and render it as appropriate.

Comment: With the edited code in the answer I am not getting redirected any advice I even created a function in local react that if the redirect is true in state to use the Redirect from react-router

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to go with my tactic of using the class syntax with the help of @Mister Epic the redirect was occurring before the action.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Form, Button, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { required, minValue7, email, renderField } from '../helpers/validations';


class SignupForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  submit(values) {
    this.props.signup(values)
    this.props.history.push('/form2')
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <Grid centered columns={2}>
          <Grid.Column className="home">
            <Form className="forms" onSubmit={ this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.submit) }>
              <Form.Field inline>
                 <Field 
                  name="username" 
                  component={renderField}
                  type="text" 
                  placeholder="Username"
                  label="Username"
                  validate={[required]}
                />
              </Form.Field>

              <Form.Field inline>
                 <Field 
                  name="email" 
                  component={renderField}
                  type="email" 
                  placeholder="Email"
                  label="Email"
                  validate={[required, email]}
                />
              </Form.Field>

               <Form.Field inline>
                 <Field 
                  name="password" 
                  component={renderField} 
                  type="password" 
                  placeholder="Password"
                  label="Password"
                  validate={[required, minValue7]}
                />
              </Form.Field>
                <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
            </Form>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>

    )
  }

}

SignupForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'form1'
})(SignupForm)


export default SignupForm
```